# Change site language depends a page id

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change the site language  dependig a page id, something like:

```
if (is_page( $page_id )){
   define('WPLANG','es_US');
}else{
   define('WPLANG','he_IL');
}
```

When I run this code I get the message: "Note: The WPLANG constant in your wp-config.php file is no longer needed." under site-language in settings.

Is there any good way to do it?

Comment: check this:- https://wpml.org/forums/topic/note-the-wplang-constant-in-your-wp-config-php-file-is-no-longer-needed/

Comment: It shows how to change only the admin area for a specific language, how it answers my question? @A-2-A